# CakePHP 1.3: CKEditor with FileManager Permission (FIXED!)

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, ckeditor, authentication, file-manager

I am trying to implement CKEditor in my **CakePHP app admin section**  with a third-party file manager (http://labs.corefive.com/2009/10/30/an-open-file-manager-for-ckeditor-3-0/).

Everything has been setup nicely, including uploading fotos, etc. However, I have one BIG issue I cant seem to figure out how to fix.

In the `filemanager.config.php` file there is the `auth()` function which prevent unauthorized use of the FileManager. **I am not sure how to implement this function as to ONLY allow my app's administrator to use**. In my user's table I use `group_id` to categorize users and the `administrators group_id` is `1`.

I've thought about `_SESSION`, but I have not been able to create a solution.

```
/**
*   Check if user is authorized
*
*   @return boolean true is access granted, false if no access
*/
function auth() {
    // You can insert your own code over here to check if the user is authorized.
    // If you use a session variable, you've got to start the session first                                               
    session_start();
    if ($_SESSION['User.group_id'] == 1){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for you help.

=====================================================================================

## EDIT

I had the whole setup wrong

1. I was using my CakePHP session as Database, I've changed it to php.
2. And my $_SESSION code was wrong

I was able to fix it per the following:

```
function auth() {
    session_name("CAKEPHP");
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['Auth']['User']) )
    {
        if($_SESSION['Auth']['User']['group_id'] == 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

It works great as such.

## ====================================================================================

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you show is from fceditor? If you set up auth in CakePHP correctly and have not modified the default session key your user data will be in $_SESSIOn['Auth']['User'].

In CakePHP do not use $_SESSION directly, use the Session component.

Comment: Fixed. Your answer gave me a hint and placed me in the right direction to my solution. First, I was using database to store my sessions and secondly the $_SESSION code was wrong. See my EDIT. THANKS!

Comment: Welcome. :) You can also configure CakePHP to use the database for sessions. It comes with php, file and database based session support and you can extend it to whatever you need. Also check the CakePHP Auth component.

Comment: Yeah, I knew about that. I have switched it back to `php` temporarily until I make a function that checks cake_session for the info I need to allow use of FileManager.